# how to more easily use reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php, recaptcha

My site uses php, and I have followed the instructions of google to add reCAPTCHA to my site. It works very effectively, but my problem is that our customers are elderly, they are difficult to recognize the importance of character reCAPTCHA, sometimes these characters also appear in reCAPTCHA urban character chemistry, mathematics, this is very difficult to use with the elderly. ReCAPTCHA has two default images the equivalent of two words, very high levels of difficulty with the automated spam programs, but sometimes difficult for users. So I want to ask which way to reduce from two photos to a photo, and reduce the difficulty of reCAPTCHA?

Comment: reCAPTCHA comes with an audio option which is an alternative at least, but perhaps equally difficult for the hard of hearing.

Comment: This isn't really a SO question.

Comment: reCAPTCHA does what it does, you can't modify it. If it's not for you, try looking for other captcha services/implementations/alternatives.

Comment: i only show a captcha if the first attempt to log in is a fail. great reduces the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Why not skip captcha and implement something else? I agree captcha can be very hard. Some other options range from "what is three plus five?" to "type the word seven." It wont be as hard for some rare spam bots, but easy for humans and your code.